# How Delphi Interop with Detours Library?

Tags: delphi, detours

I'm looking for Delphi samples, but I can find only the C++ sample codes.

For example, how to define the below hook in Delphi?

```
DETOUR_TRAMPOLINE(int   WINAPI SetScrollInfoT(HWND, int, LPCSCROLLINFO, BOOL), SetScrollInfo)
```

Comment: Why not use a native Delphi hooking library?

Comment: Like this one: [`madCodeHook`](http://help.madshi.net/madCodeHook.htm).

Comment: Thanks @David, but can you suggest one for me?

Comment: madCodeHook is superb and I think there are free ones that will also do trampolines, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: When I used it I think it was free for non-commercial. But now you have to buy it and its not cheap. He will also not just sell it to anyone because he had a lot of problems with people abusing his library for malware etc... You have to prove your intentions and he will do a background check of who you are. But all that aside its one of the most professional pieces of code I have ever used.

Comment: MadCodeHook and other products from Madshi.net are fantastic. It's worth it if you're a serious, good guy. If you're a bad person, then begone, or we shall taunt you a second time.

Comment: Thanks @Warren, i need the hook to help me skin my component. I found some Delphi Hook API, but either they're not work, or shield by the Anti-Virus, such as the MagicApiHook. Besides the MadCodeHook, any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you need to hook this in other processes, or in your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to hook inside your own process the you can look at Detours library. I recently included it in my Cromis library with the consent of the author.

You can find it [here](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/). Just download the whole lib and use Cromis.Detours. It works on 32 and 64 bit and is very well written.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks you all guys, finally i got this [Ring3HookLibrary](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicscounterstrikewireleases/ring3hooklibrary)